# Configuring Azure Diagnostics for Azure Application Service (PaaS)

Tags: azure, paas, azure-diagnostics

**My setup:** Existing WCF service project modified to run as Azure Application Service (PaaS). 
Originally I used log4net for my info/error logging, but it is rather cumbersome to look at those logs via FTP or SCM console. After some research I came to a conclusion that Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics is the recommended way to handle logging in Azure apps. 
**Question/problem:** I can't find a guide, for my scenario, on how to enable WindowsAzure Diagnostics for Application Service that is NOT created as Web/Worker Role.
The closest I got is [Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/) cmdlet, but it requires Role as parameter...

Comment: You may want to check out custom solutions. See [www.trypour.com](http://www.trypour.com) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, but using standard Diagnostics classes is preferable in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question/problem: I can't find a guide, for my scenario, on how to
>   enable WindowsAzure Diagnostics for Application Service that is NOT
>   created as Web/Worker Role.

You can't use Azure Diagnostics for your Azure Application Service. It is meant for Azure Cloud Service (Web/Worker Role) and Azure Virtual Machines.

For App Services diagnostics, please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, one more question though that is not clear from the article, is there a way for Azure Application Service to write traces into Table storage or local FS and Blobs are the only options?

Comment: I have not used this feature but reading the documentation I am inferring that transferring data into table storage is definitely supported. I don't think this functionality is exposed yet in the new Azure portal. If you can, use old portal to do so. Also, see if you can use Azure PowerShell to do the same. Please read this section on classic portal & PowerShell: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/#enablediag. HTH.